# Elasticsearch Java API Function Score Query with script function

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently trying to build this function score query with the Java API of elasticsearch:

```
"query": {
"function_score": {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": " ( ((Feild1:\"KeyWord\"^100)  OR (Feild2:\"KeyWord\"^50) ))",
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "boost_mode": "replace",
  "script_score": {
    "script": "_score * doc [ 'calc_feild'].value"
  }
}
```

But I can't find any documentation regarding the java api and the function score queries. This is what I have so far:

So far I realized it

```
searchParam = ((Feild1:\"KeyWord\"^100)  OR (Feild2:\"KeyWord\"^50))
searchBulider.setQuery(new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(QueryBuilders.queryString(searchParam).defaultOperator(Operator.AND)).boostMode("replace"));
```

query

```
"query" : {
"function_score" : {
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : " (  ((Feild1:\"KeyWord\"^100)  OR (Feild2:\"KeyWord\"^50) ) )",
      "default_operator" : "and"
    }
  },
  "functions" : [ ],
  "boost_mode" : "replace"
}
```

I do not know the method in the future
 And the next question is how I can provide to functions in the FunctionScore Builder

Function empty?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right way, here is the whole code to build the desired query:

```
searchParam = "((Feild1:\"KeyWord\"^100)  OR (Feild2:\"KeyWord\"^50))";
QueryStringQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryString(searchParam)
    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND);
ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder scoreFunction = ScoreFunctionBuilders
    .scriptFunction("_score * doc['calc_feild'].value");
searchBulider.setQuery(new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(query, scoreFunction)
    .boostMode("replace"));
```

Comment: Thanks to you I approached the answer!
However, only the part of "new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(query, scoreFunction" gets an error.it's"
Constructor FunctionScoreQueryBuilder (QueryStringQueryBuilder, ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder) is undefined"
The version of Elasticsearch.jar uses 1.1.2.
Do you have an answer what to do?

Comment: I solved it!
The code is modified like this ⇒ "new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(query).add(scoreFunction).boostMode("replace")"
Thank you very much! It is!

Comment: Yeah, that was out of memory ;-) Glad you figured it out.